# Gradle install not updating the jar

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I am using gradle install and surprisingly my jar in /m2 repository not udpating.

Even though I deleted the folder and then did gradle install, I am unable to see the latest jar. The old jar is again getting created.
I did gradle install just now and see what happened (no errors) :

[image]

Below is my build.gradle
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven'
group = 'bt'
version = '1.0'

```
repositories{ 
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
} 



dependencies { 
        compile('bt:daoconfig:1.0')
        compile('bt:common:1.0')
       testCompile 'org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.2.8'
       testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-mockito-release-full:1.6.4'
       testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
       testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:1.5.2.RELEASE'
}
```

Kindly let me know what wrong i am doing?

thanks

Comment: I used gradle clean , then gradle install. It got updated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used gradle clean , then gradle install. It got updated. Thanks